# PUT Method Restriction with ModSecurity

Tags: php, laravel, put

InmotionHosting tell me that PUT / DELETE Method are restricted by **ModSecurity**.

They tell me that direct PUT request is not posible, but that I can do it with PHP.

They also tell me they can disable those restriction, but that it would expose my system to security breach and that it is not recommended.

I don't really understand the concept of direct / indirect PUT...

More, I have no clue of what should I do in PHP to make PUT request without doing it directly.

I'm working with Laravel / PHP / Apache

Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What InmotionHosting told you is simply not true. There's no security implication if you use a `PUT` request. When you look at raw `http` message, there's no real possibility of a security exploit - it's just another HTTP verb. I'd suggest switching hosting provider, if those guys are going so far that they claim a `PUT` exposes something to security breach in year 2015. then they have no clue what they're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's documentation is great for this: [Form Method Spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Now in your laravel router/controller you can check in the Request->input('_method')

```
if( Request->input('_method') === "put")
{
    //do something
    ...
}
```

And you can run code specifically for this form in that route or controller. So you don't really need to open yourself to those commands but you can still handle them. More information about requests [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#request-information) and [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests)

Comment: What I don't understand is why shouldn't I expose PUT Method if it is part of REST specification?

Comment: Depending on the actual web server itself, this could be a command that causes something special to happen. If you're on a shared server, this is disabled by default since it can cause file uploads from a client to places on your server you don't want them going to that the web server itself is doing before it ever hits your application.

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro did this answer your question?